# User registration

Tags: plugins, user-registration, members

I'm working on a WP project where I want the user to be able to register via my WP page, and later I want to receive a mail about this user info, To either confirm or deny their registration (this I want to be used as a way for new members to join my association via my website).

I was using the Ultimate Member plugin but I don't want users to be able to log in on my site and have their own pages and be able to interact on the site etc.

So should I do it some other way or stick with Ultimate member?